# Auto Fetch Lyric in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, google-search, audio-player

Hello So i am doing a project about music player.And i added a feature that there is a browser that will redirect to that song's lyric when the music player changes song.

But there is a problem,i am using google's im feeling lucky api `(http://google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&btnI=1&q=)` ,and this is my code (I am using visual basic):

```
Private Sub Player_CurrentItemChange(sender As Object, e As AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_CurrentItemChangeEvent) Handles Player.CurrentItemChange
    If My.Settings.lyricenable = True Then
        Dim Artist As String = Player.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.getItemInfo("Artist")
        Dim Title As String = Player.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.getItemInfo("Title")
        lyricsbrowser.Navigate("http://google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&btnI=1&q=" + Title + "+" + Artist + "+Lyrics")

    End If
End Sub
```

(lyricenable is a setting where the user can enable auto lyric finding or disbale it)

So i run the program, and i found that **some of them** worked (For example `http://google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&btnI=1&q=Pompeii+Bastille+lyrics`, this goes to http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/bastille/pompeii.html)

But some of them showed google's all the search result (For example https://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=navclient&btnI=1&q=Problem+Pentatonix+Lyrics)

Where is the problem? I am newbie in VB so i know just these. Tell me if there are better ways. Thank you!

(Sorry but stackoverfow only allow me to have 2 link so i block quoted some link)

Comment: why not tap into one of the many lyric APIs?  Google is not perfect, so the Lucky method will fail on occassion

Comment: Thanks @Plutonix Because at that i wasn't really know much about lyric APIs, can you clarify some of the lyric APIs? I can give up with google's lucky. In fact i use google im feeling lucky because i believe that google have ALL the songs' lyric.

Comment: Google does not have *any* song lyrics, Google just knows which sites have the song lyrics.

Comment: that's what i want to say! my english is bad but google know which site have the lyric. I am sorry Plutonix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you could try:

1. As mentioned in comments, the most efficient way is probably to use a lyrics API, such as http://api.wikia.com/wiki/LyricWiki_API. This would be fairly hard to do in VB.Net if you're not an experienced developer, but it might be possible with a WebRequest().
2. You could use another search engine - Bing used to have a Best Match feature but I think it is deprecated. DuckDuckGo (great search engine, by the way), has an Instant Answers API (https://duckduckgo.com/api) which you may be able to use.
3. Use an internal site search, which searches for the lyrics only on one site. It's just a matter of finding a lyrics site that has a wide range of lyrics. If the site has a built-in site search you can use that, or create a Google custom search for it (see `https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630963?hl=en`).
4. Alternatively, just go to the direct URL of a specific site if you know the format. You may be able to use regular expressions (RegEx) to format the URL for the song correctly, and try several formats in If statements.

Three and four are probably the easieat to do in VB.Net, but they're not as reliable. I guess you could always combine multiple methods as a fallback. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you for responding my answer, here is my respond of ur respond:
1.Lyric API is very interesting for me, especially the REST-like method, but if i use it, i just don't know how to parse the url to my program since it just shows part of the lyrics
2.DuckDuckGo is good, but it is too complicate for me. Moreover, it returns too many results which i just want one.
3.Google custom search is also a good way to do it, i personally uses azlyrics.com since it has all the songs' lyrics, but the script is in html.... is there a way to change it to vb.net?
To be continued...

Comment: 4. If i understand your meaning, i guess u are saying for example http://lyrics.wikia.com/(Artist):(Song) or http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/(artist)/(song).html
but this method it would pretty hard to format the song **CORRETLY**

Any ways Thank you for responding and i will see which way is better for me.